# Download file using FTP doesnt work

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to download a file from my FTP server using this code:

```
        public byte[] DownloadFile(string remoteFile)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ip + '/' + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(getFileSize(remoteFile))];
            int bytesRead = byteBuffer.Length;
            ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;                
            Console.WriteLine("Successful");
            return byteBuffer;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
            return bytes;
        }
```

But always, the FileZilla server stops sending data at 87.7% 
Is this a problem in my code or whats the problem?

Comment: did you get an exception ?

Comment: use `ftpStream.CopyTo(ms);` where `ms` is an instance of an `MemoryStream` see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx .  you can then  `return ms.ToArray();` to get the bytebuffer.

Comment: You should learn the basics of streams. A stream does not have to return all the amount of data you have requested, so more than one read may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Rene found the answer:

```
public byte[] DownloadFile(string remoteFile)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ip + '/' + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            //byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(getFileSize(remoteFile))];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ftpStream.CopyTo(ms);
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;                
            Console.WriteLine("Successful");
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that you are not reading all of the data.  Try reading from the stream regardless of how many bytes it tells you that it has until you get to the end of the stream.

```
Action<string, string> downloadBrowser = null;
downloadBrowser = new Action<string, string>((tempDir, file) => {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Downloading file '{0}'", file));

    const int bufferLength = 1024;
    var megaByteSize = (bufferLength * 500);

    var dlRequest = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(FTP_SITE + file);
    dlRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    dlRequest.UseBinary = true;

    using (var dlResponse = dlRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        var dlResponseStream = dlResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var fileName = Path.Combine(tempDir, file);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {               
            var buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
            var progressLimit = megaByteSize;
            var bytesRead = 0;
            do {
                bytesRead = dlResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                if (fs.Length > progressLimit) {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    progressLimit += megaByteSize;
                }
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDownload Complete");
});
```